# How do I poll a database on the background and notify with SignalR from the server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am currently working on a live chat app using SignalR. The live chat app works like this:

1. An registered user can only talk with an admin. There
   can be any number of admins connected at the same time.
2. Each admin can talk to any registered user (even those offline) whenever they choose.
3. The user side of the chat app and the admin side are in two different ASP.NET MVC apps, sharing the same database. (this is a user requirement)
4. All messages are stored in the database as soon as they are sent.

Currently I have both apps call a SignalR server function which fetches data from the database using setInterval() to update the client, but that defeats the whole point of using SignalR. Is there a way to poll the database with a background task on the server side, and then notify a specific user (the one receiving the message) using SignalR? If so, how do I set up the background task?

Comment: tbh, that design beats the whole purpose of real time chatting and it's making your apps more convoluted without any gains

Comment: whats ur database? if its MSSQL then you need `SQL Dependency`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a bottom to top notification mechanism (Database-Application-Client). As [@JAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859774/how-do-i-poll-a-database-on-the-background-and-notify-with-signalr-from-the-serv/38893647#comment65127438_38859774) correcty suggested you may use [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx) from ADO.Net's toolset, which will let you put a wach on your messages table so you will be notified once it changes (for instance, a message gets inserted). Here's a [fine example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx). SqlDependency will not give you the actual record that was inserted/changed - it will just let you know that there has been a change, so you'll need to design a query that will fetch that exact record. Once you receive a notification you may query that record then call client's method from your hub and pass a record as an argument.